# Formulário dinâmico com contador

Tags: javascript, formulário, contador

Olá, tenho um formulário dinâmico e em um dos inputs necessito que ao clicar no botão que adiciona um novo input a sua label apresente um contador em ordem crescente, da mesma maneira  quando for necessário remover um dos inputs seja decrementado do contador. Não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar da forma esperada. Segue trechos do código HTML

```
        <div id="optionsForm" style="display:none">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 mt-3">
                    <label for="ipt-option">Opção 1</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="ipt-option" placeholder="Texto do botão">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAddOption"  style="margin-top: 48px;"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

E o JavaScript

```
var optionsForm = 1;

$(document).on("click", "[id^=btnAddOption]", function () {    
    $("#optionsForm").append(`<div class="form-group-row" id="contentOptionsForm` + optionsForm + `">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-6 mt-3">
                        <label for="ipt-option">Opção&nbsp;<span id="counter"></span></label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="ipt-option" placeholder="Texto do botão">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="removeOptionsForm_` + optionsForm + `" style="margin-top: 48px;"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </div>                    
                </div>`);

    optionsForm++;

    const btnAdd$ = document.getElementById("btnAddOption");
    const btnRemove$ = document.getElementById("removeOptionsForm_");
    const counter$ = document.getElementById("counter");

    let counter = 2;


    btnAdd$.addEventListener('click', function () {
        counter$.innerHTML = ++counter;

    });

    btnAdd$.addEventListener('click', function () {
       counter$.innerHTML = --counter;
    });
    
});

$(document).on("click", "[id^=removeOptionsForm_]", function () {
    var id = $(this)[0].id.split('_')[1];    
    $("#contentOptionsForm" + id).remove();
});
```

Comment: Achei a resposta que precisava no link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159690/how-to-update-number-sequence-column-when-remove-item-from-item-detail-in-html-t e adaptei para o meu código.

Comment: Aqui `<div id="optionsForm" style="display:none">` o exemplo inicia com um documento em branco para o usuário não permitindo interação alguma.

Comment: Na verdade esse não era o problema, aqui apenas demonstrei parte do código, mas essa div realmente inicia em branco pq é habilitada após seleção de um radio  button. De qualquer forma o problema foi selecionado adaptando e seguindo os passos do link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159690/how-to-update-number-sequence-column-when-remove-item-from-item-detail-in-html-t